# Enable Debug Mode in Android Google Exposure API

Tags: android, coronasdk

I am developing an app using the Google Exposure API and trying to turn on Debug Mode. In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/exposure-notifications/debug-mode) it says:

> To enable debug mode on a device, the primary account on the device
> must be a development account that is on the allowlist.

How to get on to this "allowlist"?
Or is there a workaround, so that you can enable the debug mode without the need for the allowlist account?

Comment: Will rooting the device help us?

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [glossary](https://developers.google.com/android/exposure-notifications/exposure-notifications-api#gloss_allowlisted) related to Exposure API, it says

> Allowlisted accounts We have partnered with public health agencies for
> purposes of collaboration and testing of Exposure Notifications apps
> while they are in development. An allowlist grants specific
> permissions for these Google partners.

So I suppose you need to agree with the Public Health Authority in your country in order to be able to get an allowlist account from Google.

Comment: If only this works... I have the whitelisted account as the ONLY one on the device and it still doesn't work. Well, it does one day and doesn't a day after... Well done, Google.